# Accessing field in springSecurity.userAccountDetails

Tags: java, spring

To display the currently logged in user's information, I need access to the user's ID as the username is not unique. The User details I get from getPrincipal() already contain an "id" field, yet I can't access it using this method (throws NoSuchFieldException).

```
@GetMapping("/account")
    String account(Model model){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String userName= auth.getName();
        Object Principal = auth.getPrincipal();
        UUID id = Principal.getClass().getField("id");
```

The structure printed in the console looks like this: SpringSecurityAuthenticationManagement.UserAccountDetails(id=..., username=..., password=..., isEnabled=..., authorities=...). How can I access only the ID property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the question. There are several ways to display the currently logged-in user's information.

1. From SecurityContextHolder

The SecurityContextHolder is where Spring Security stores the details of who is authenticated. Spring Security does not care how the SecurityContextHolder is populated. If it contains a value, it is used as the currently authenticated user.

```java
@GetMapping("/account/your-custom-path-0")
public String getAccountIdFromSecurityContextHolder() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserAccountDetails userAccountDetails = (UserAccountDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    UUID uuid = userAccountDetails.getId();
    return uuid.toString();
}
```

Please refer to [Spring Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder).

2. From HttpServletRequest

HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() returns the result of SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). This means that it is an Authentication, which is typically an instance of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken when using username- and password-based authentication. This can be useful if you need additional information about your user.

```java
@GetMapping("/account/your-custom-path-1")
public String getAccountIdFromHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    UserAccountDetails userAccountDetails = (UserAccountDetails) httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
    UUID uuid = userAccountDetails.getId();
    return uuid.toString();
}
```

Please refer to [Spring Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/servlet-api.html#servletapi-user-principal).

3. Using AuthenticationPrincipal Annotation

Spring Security provides AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver, which can automatically resolve the current Authentication.getPrincipal() for Spring MVC arguments. By using @EnableWebSecurity, you automatically have this added to your Spring MVC configuration.

```java
@GetMapping("/account/your-custom-path-2")
public String getAccountIdUsingAuthenticationPrincipalAnnotation(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
    UserAccountDetails userAccountDetails = (UserAccountDetails) userDetails;
    UUID uuid = userAccountDetails.getId();
    return uuid.toString();
}
```

Please refer to [Spring Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal).

4. From Authentication

The Authentication contains ... principal: Identifies the user. When authenticating with a username/password this is often an instance of UserDetails.

```java
@GetMapping("/account/your-custom-path-3")
public String getAccountIdFromAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
    UserAccountDetails userAccountDetails = (UserAccountDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    UUID uuid = userAccountDetails.getId();
    return uuid.toString();
}
```

Please refer to [Spring Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-authentication).

You may also refer to [Baeldung - Retrieve User Information in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security), which also gives you some information on this issue.
Please tell me if the links above become invalid in the future.

---

**Updated**

The class `UserAccountDetails` needs to implement `UserDetails` like this:

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class UserAccountDetails implements UserDetails {
    private UUID id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public UserAccountDetails(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getters and setters
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null; // please use your own settings 
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        UserAccountDetails that = (UserAccountDetails) object;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id)
                && Objects.equals(username, that.username)
                && Objects.equals(password, that.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // may be useful when debugging
        return "UserAccountDetails {" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is obvious, but is UserAccountDetails a spring package I need to import or something I need to define in one of my own classes? Because I really didn't find anything named "UserAccountDetails" in spring security and am slightly confused. Thanks for your detailed help though.

Comment: @xenia Sorry, since you wrote `SpringSecurityAuthenticationManagement.UserAccountDetails` in your question, I thought that you had written your entity class which is named "UserAccountDetails". Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserAccountDetails userAccountDetails = (UserAccountDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
UUID id = userAccountDetails.getId()
```